# When to use an object in a vector and when to use a pointer to an object in a vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, raii

When you instantiate objects and store them in a vector.
What are the pros and cons between these three and in which instance should these be used?

Object:

```
std::vector<obj> collection;
collection.push_back(obj{});
```

Pointer to object:

```
std::vector<obj*> collection;
collection.push_back(new obj{});
```

Smart Pointer:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<obj>> collection;
collection.push_back(std::unique_ptr<obj>(new obj{}));
```

Comment: it depends on the lifetime of the object you want to handle

Comment: It also depends on whether your object can be safely and/or efficiently copied or not.

Comment: @MarcoA. In the case of RAII and smart Pointer, wouldn't the lifetime of the object depend on the lifetime of the std::vector?

Comment: @worker11811 Yes.  In which case, you're almost always better off using the first approach (which I certainly wouldn't qualify as RAII).

Comment: short answer - use the object unless you can't, in which case use a smart pointer

Comment: @JamesKanze Pardon my ignorance, but why wouldn't it qualify as RAII?

Comment: @worker11811 an object is created and then destroyed, this is not RAII. If you deal with resources acquisition/release and are interested in exception handling and encapsulation, that falls under the RAII idiom.

Comment: @MarcoA. Yes, I guess taking the first and the smart pointer approach couples into RAII.  So maybe I should call the first approach something else?

Comment: Not sure of how you could rename it, but I wouldn't call it RAII either

Answer (score 3):

If the object type supports copy and assignment, you should
eschew pointers, and put the object in the vector (and
everywhere else—you probably shouldn't have any pointers
to such an object).

If the object type has identity, and doesn't support copy and
assignment (or only supports copy in order to implement
a `clone` function), then you'll need to keep pointers in the
vector.  Whether smart pointers or raw pointers depends on what
the vector is being used for, and what the policy concerning the
lifetime of the object are.  In my experience, most of the time,
vectors are used for navigation, in which case, you should use
raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

- The first approach is the classic one, the objects will be destroyed at the end of the container's life. It might have the drawback of operations like `std::sort` where a lot of moving around is involved compared to a simple pointer (if this is at all a problem in the case of a specific object). Notice that this might be the preferred approach with objects supporting copy/assignment.
- The second approach might have additional speed (holding huge objects with poor copy/move performances in a container is always a bad idea) but has the drawback of having to deal with freeing the memory yourself unless you want to keep those objects around after the container's destruction.
- The third approach is more or less as fast as the second for sorting operations plus it has the advantage of using a smart pointer which will ensure memory is automatically freed when the container goes out of scope.

It really boils down to your objects' intended lifetime scope and how efficiently your objects can be copied around. **Do some profiling for your intended test case** and don't decide 'a priori' which one should be used (as James points out that might be a case of premature optimization).

Comment: You may ultimately have to use pointers instead of copy if the profiler says so, but this is rare.  Especially if you make the objects support move semantics.  Using pointers for value objects is a classical case of premature optimization.

Comment: Right, I believe there's no single shot answer to this question.

Comment: I used the smart pointer approach in a project a while ago, it was required due to the size of the objects we were passing (>1GiB).  For anything else, I'd favor the first approach _most of the time_

Comment: @Baldrickk woah, never used objects that big. That gives an entirely new sense to "pass-by-value", more on the "pass-by-elephant"

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use the first option as much as possible unless there is a compelling reason to use the other one (the other two are almost equivalent anyway so not much difference there).

The main reason is that it results in cleaner code and it is almost certainly better for RAII (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) because the compiler generates the code that has no leaks whatsoever. Some people here are pointing out performance concerns which are valid but they are rarer than what most people seem to think.

So bottom line (IMHO) is: go for the simplest and the cleanest option unless there is compelling reason to do otherwise. Do not add needless complexities in your application unless you absolutely have to. I have seen too much code errors because of premature optimizations that are not even needed most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

If your object is simple data, then the first option is always best. New memory is allocated and managed internally by the vector object, so you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Vector of objects. Useful for items that are generally passed by value, easy to copy.
2. Vector of raw pointers. For more complex objects (those you don't want to copy), efficient to copy but somewhere you have to manage the lifetime of these pointers. Even if you delete when you remove the item from the vector, you have to know there are no dangling ones about. This can be the best approach on occasions where the objects' lifetime is managed elsewhere and you know these pointers will remain valid, and you just want to pump them in a vector for some use, e.g. an API that returns a subset of a bigger collection could do so as a vector of pointers to those objects.
3. More commonly `shared_ptr` has been used for this, because the vector owns one copy and whoever extracts one to read / use gets another copy, so the lifetime issue doesn't occur. With unique_ptr it is pretty much a policy that it is owned by the vector and the main reason for this over (2) is not having to manually delete it when it is removed from the vector. The vector needs to be wrapped within a class controlling it. Use of `shared_ptr` here has, for years, been the generally recommended construct when you are not storing objects themselves for the general safety of lifetime guarantees.